# What is the name of this font?

Tags: graphics, fonts

What is the name of this font? :

[image: http://i54.tinypic.com/2vv1jq9.png]

Comment: Go to www.myfonts.com and ask there.

Comment: It's probably a Microsoft internal font ...

Comment: How is this off-topic? aren't fonts part of css?

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=y&ch%5B1%5D=m&ch%5B2%5D=s&wtfserver=node5.ric.mf&id=00023b0e4cc35811000b0a4900006615&glyphcount=3&imageid=0) you are.

**EDIT:** Following Mark Ransom's suggestion I'm adding the link to the [site](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) where the results were obtained. To find a font as close to the original as possible, kindly upload an image that contains as many characters as possible. The results obtained **may** not be the exact same font that you are looking for, however a large training set will ensure that you at arrive something as close to the original. Thanks Mark

Comment: I don't see the answer in those results, sorry.

Comment: @Mark as drachenstern mentioned it's quite possible that it is an internal Microsoft font. However xRobot may feed in a larger image to increase his chances of finding a font as close to it as possible. If you see closely the only big difference between blue highway expanded and the msn font is in the tail of the y. You could perhaps give it a try by uploading the complete image.

Comment: it's quite misleading to give a link without any mention that the answer is not quite correct. Besides it's now a dead link. By going to the site and submitting the sample yourself you can pass it to a forum if you don't get the right answer, and the forum is absolutely amazing at finding obscure fonts.

Comment: Agreed Mark, my bad, however given the small input/training set the neural-ocr engine did deliver a font as close to the original as possible.