# What is the name of this font?

Tags: css, fonts

[image]

Comment: I invite you to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and find out what questions belong here.

Comment: Remember you had a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080362/what-is-the-name-of-this-font-closed) closed? Yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [this](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) site. Hope it manages to help you:)